# my program is telling that the a certain variable is undefined, how do I fix it?

Tags: python

Python is telling me "undefined name 'sorted_by_pages' " I'm not completely sure how to fix it or how to define it as I am new to python in general. Any advice, tips or tricks? also have to email this code to my prof if I send the code like this will he be able to open the excel file? I was also thinking about sending the excel file in a zip file with the code: will this help or should I do something else?

```
import webbrowser
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
webbrowser.open('https://www.kaggle.com/jealousleopard/goodreadsbooks/version/6')
import pandas as pd 
excel_file='books93.xls'
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Evelyn\Desktop\books93.xls")
sorted_by_pages['# num_pages'].plot(kind="hist")
print (df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unless your prof is called `Evelyn` and has a file called `books93.xls` on his desktop, he won't be able to use your program as is. As for your error, try changing `sorted_by_pages` to `df`

Answer (score 0):

modify `df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Evelyn\Desktop\books93.xls")` to `df=pd.read_excel(r"book93.xls")` 
  and
`sorted_by_pages['# num_pages'].plot(kind="hist")` to `df['# num_pages'].plot(kind="hist")`

Comment: will this allow any user to open the excel sheet?

Comment: yes just send your professor excel sheet and code in a zip folder

Comment: Make sure you don't create two folders, both the code and excel file should be in the same folder,

Comment: they are in the same folder but canopy keeps telling me the file doesn't exist

Comment: did u create any subfolder in the folder? and make sure folder name is correct

Comment: and btw there is no need for the statement excel_file='books93.xls' in your code

Comment: Check whether folder name you have entered is not wrong, try closing the python editor and opening it